# Use unnamed object to invoke method or not?

Tags: c++, coding-style, refactoring

If I have a class with only only public method. When I use this class, is it good to use unnamed object to invoke its method?

normal:

```
TaxFileParser tax_parser(tax_file_name);
auto content = tax_parser.get_content();
```

or unnamed object version:

```
auto content = TaxFileParser(tax_file_name).get_content();
```

Because I've told that we should avoid temporary as possible. If `tax_parser` object is used only once, can I call it a temporary and try to eliminate it?

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temporary object is still created, whether you gave it a name or not. Your two lines are equivalent.

If there is only one public method, I'd ask why this is even a class. Can it be handled by being a function with `tax_file_name` as parameter? *Then* you would not have an otherwise useless temporary object.

```
class TaxFileParser
{
   public:
     static whatever_t get_content(const std::string& file)
     {
       return result_from_file_in_question();
     }
};

auto content = TaxFileParser::get_content(tax_file_name);
```

Comment: Maybe there are some necessary data members or data function as helpers the TaxFileParser need, so that those members are needed to be grouped into one class. like TaxFileParser::parse_header(), TaxFileParser::parse_body(), TaxFileParser::m_fstream, etc...

Comment: Personally, I think if those two (constructor and parameterless function) are the only public interfaces, the whole class can be made into a single static class where every other function is a static helper and every piece of formerly class data is local variables that must be passed between the functions. That way, the interaction of the functions is way better documented. Side effects of methods (for example modifying class data) is hard to track so if this class *can* be made easier, I'd go for easier.

Comment: Even if the c'tor and `get_content` are the only public methods, it might still be worthwhile to have an object. For example, if `get_content` comes from an "interface"(yea, C++ doesn't have interfaces, but you know what I mean) and you want to be able to pass around instances that implement that interface, so you can parse tax from different sources. Another case is when you want to pass `tax_file_name` in one place(with the possibility of adding more arguments later) and call `get_content` in another place.

Comment: @nvoigt: Not a static class, a _function_. Non-member, namespaced.

Comment: @ChenOT: You can always create an instance inside the function. But why bother the caller with creating one when it's the only way to use it.

Comment: @nvoigt But those data member and functions in TaxFileParser are  related closely, why I shouldn't put in one class and separate theme as independent static/non-member functions instead?

Comment: @JanHudec because sometimes I am also the client to call my class. And I just wonder is it right or acceptable to invoke method by unnamed object if I use the object once.

Comment: @ChenOT From the looks, your class does not need data members. Maybe it does something under the hood we don't know, but at face value, you could pass your constructor parameters to get_content() instead and get rid of the class. That way you don't need an object at all.

Comment: @JanHudec You are right about the free function and namespace. I've been coding C# for too long :)

Comment: @ChenOT: If you use the object once, it is better to use anonymous object than named one. What is not good is having to instantiate an object to use it only once. It should be instantiated internally on the other side of the interface in such cases.

Answer (score 4):

Placing an object in a variable because you've been "told that we should avoid temporary as possible" is like using static variables because you've been told singletons are bad - you are not really avoiding the problem, only the code smell that comes with the most common form of the problem.

Like nvoigt says, if you want to avoid that problem altogether you should change the method to something that doesn't create objects. However, it might not be possible(maybe you can't modify the object's source code?) or reasonable(maybe the class has other methods, and you don't want to mess up the design) to do so. In that case - I believe the first approach(unnamed temporary object) is better.

The main difference between the two approaches is when the destructor of the temporary object will be called. If it's a named temporary object, it'll be called at the end of the scope. If it's an unnamed temporary object, it'll be called after the call to `get_content()`, when the object is no longer needed.

I've played a bit with `objdump` and found out that if you put only these two(or one) line in a function, the only difference between the two is that in the unnamed version the object is destroyed before the result of `get_content` is moved to `content` while in the named version it happens afterwards.

However, when I added an instruction to print `content` after those lines, things get a bit more complicated. The named version produced the code for calling the destructor **twice** - once at the end of the function, and once at a later point *that never gets executed*! Or, should I say, never gets executed *in the regular flow of the function*.

I'm not that familiar with how C++ works assembly-wise, but I assume this has something to do with exceptions handling - when the printing method(well, operator...) throws an exception, the stack unwinding mechanism needs to be able to call the destructors, so it uses that code.

To test this assumption, I've added a `throw` statement to `get_content`, and as I expected now the unnamed version also got that code segment, since now it can also get an exception before the normal destruction takes place. But still - `gcc` managed to optimize that away when it wasn't needed!

So, in conclusion - choose the unnamed version! Modern compilers are very smart but they can't read your mind, so the cues you provide them about your intentions the better job they can do. Using the unnamed version cues the optimizer that you only need the object for `get_content` and it's free to dispose of it afterwise and optimize things that way. The more things happen between an object's creation and it's destruction the harder it is for the optimizer to reason about it's role.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary variables are even worse than temporary unnamed values. To use a temporary variable, you have to come up with a name for it and everybody reading the code has to read that name, remember what it means and check it's extent.

There are good reasons to implement functionality by a class. But if it only has one method that is only called once on an instance, the class is an implementation detail. The public API should be a function like:

```
whatever_t parse_tax(string const &tax_file_name) {
    return TaxFileParser(tax_file_name).get_content();
}
```

C++ is multi-paradigmatic langue. It does not require everything to be in a class. So only put things in them if it has actual meaning.